# Visualize AngularJSApp

Tags: angularjs, visualization

I'm new to AngularJS and i'm wondering what's a good way to visualize a AngularJS app (with UML classdiagram/componentdiagram)? And the reason why.

Can you give a example?

I found this, but don't know if this is a right way: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/visually-representing-angular-applications/

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You want to create a model of a basic AngularJS app behavior ? Have you seen this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts ?

Comment: I want to create a UML model for my Angular app, but i'm not shure where to start. I will change this in my question

Comment: This might be of use, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/299174/uml-modeling-angular-controllers-factories-and-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Class Diagram to represent your Controllers, Factories, Services, etc (as show in the link provided by M22an in comments). In this diagram, you can easily show the methods and attributes of each Controller / Service / Factory.

You can use a Sequence Diagram to represent the communication between the parts of your app. Show each method, show which part of a service it calls, the data given and received, the update of the template with the $apply method etc.

A component diagram can be useful to explicit the content of each module and show the Controllers / Services / Factories... inside it. You can show the modules dependencies using this diagram too.

In my opinion, you can use almost all diagrams you want, AngularJS is huge, powerful and complex, and each UML diagram will be useful to represent a part of his behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This is the answer I was looking for. It confirms my thoughts that there is not one-way-to-go.